# What does it mean to set up a "Jupiter API artifact"?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, junit5

```
dependencies{
testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}
```

The above code seems to be what is necessary to add to the dependencies part of the build.gradle file, to run junit 5 tests in a gradle project. But it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupiter API prvides basic interfaces and annotations for test implementation. It is included correctly.
How exactly it *is not working*?

If you just cannot get your tests run, you most probably forgot to ask Gradle to run them. Check Gradle version.

In case you have Gradle 4.6+ , [you can](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.2/user-guide/#running-tests-build-gradle) configure *test* task with a built-in support

```
test {
   useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

If your Gradle is older, then you need *junit-platform-gradle-plugin*, which is going to be discontinued.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies{
testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2")
}
```

This works instead.